# Computing the arithmetic mean of the roots of a quartic polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I was checking my solution to the 1977 A1 Putnam problem [here](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/psoln/psol771.html), when I became confused about a particular step employed in the solution.

> The x-coordinates satisfy $$2x^4 + 7x^3 + (3-a)x -(5+b)$$. This has at most 4 roots, so the arithmetic mean of these roots is $$\frac{1}{4}\cdot -\frac{7}{2}=-\frac{7}{8}$$

I solved the problem with a very laborious and inelegant approach. Was there a formula here that he used to compute the arithmetic mean? Does it involve the coefficients of the polynomial similar to the rational roots theorem? Given that the problem was from 1977, I couldn't find much discussion about it on the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Vieta's, we have that the sum of the roots is $\frac{-7}{2}$. In general, for a polynomial $a_nx^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \dots + a_0$, the sum of the roots is $\frac{-a_{n-1}}{a_n}$. Look up Vieta's Formula.